# Remove the Blue Glow in Bootstrap 2

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

When I have data inside of the input, blue light will display in the input's background and I want to remove it in bootstrap 2.

I just want a white background in the input box only.

Please remember that I'm using bootstrap 2!

Thanks!

http://jsbin.com/vomukomune/edit?html,css,js,output

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The blue glow is a `box-shadow` that gets applied by the Bootstrap CSS to an `<input>` when it receives focus. You can override this with a style of your own with the `:focus` pseudo-class, for example:

```
.text-input-wrapper input:focus {
  box-shadow: none;
}
```

I've [updated the JSBin](http://jsbin.com/vuzikonazu/edit?html,css,js,output) to include this style, so you should no longer be seeing the blue glow. Hope this helps! Let me know if you have any questions.

**EDIT:** In the same way, the gray inner shadow you observe in the `<input>` is also a `box-shadow`. So you can address it by adding this to your current style declarations:

```
.text-input-wrapper input {
  box-shadow: none;
}
```

The JSBin has now been updated to reflect this change.

Comment: Thank you for your help! I also need help about removing the shadow.
I tried to apply the solution in the big test environment but it doesn't and I wonder if it possible to make the css sourcecode as a primary number one to make the html code to read the css? I was thinking about "style" but in this context it is lots of css code and I don't know how to do it in relation to style. Thanks!

Comment: @HelloWorld Happy to help out! I've added a bit more to the answer for the new shadow you mention.

Comment: Thank you for your help!